# How to Increase Header font size and remove Square bracket from output

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to increase the font of the header, remove the square bracket and the double quotation mark, in my report without any success.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

The code is I ran is shown below:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, size='huge'}
filename<-'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Title.txt'
readChar(filename,nchars=1e6)
```
````

The output I got is shown below:

```
[1] "Seasonal Events: Sales of Gift Cards and Chocolate During Festive Period
    in Rural Mons"
```

The expected result I want( Though not necessary bold face but I want the size to be bigger than default):

**Seasonal Events: Sales of Gift cards and Chocolate During Festive Period
                 in Rural Mons.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, size='huge', results="asis"}
filename<-'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Title.txt'
cat("<h3>", readChar(filename,nchars=1e6), "</h3>\n")
```
````

ought to do it

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I couldn't resolve the size issue with the code. I also noticed that the square bracket and double quotation marks was replaced with <h3> ...<h3>.  I edited the 3rd line of code to cat("",readChar(filename,nchars=1e6),"") and it solves the problem of square bracket and double quotation mark.

Comment: did you add the `results="asis"`?